# How to export SQL Server Express database or specific table to SQL file?

Tags: import, export, backup, sql-server-2012-express

I have SQL Server 2012 Express and I want to export the whole database or certain tables to a `.SQL` file (SQL Script). `.BAK` file will not work in my case.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/147638/dump-microsoft-sql-server-database-to-an-sql-script

Comment: thanks. is there any way to do it with sqlcmd? or maybe it is possible to create a procedure and call it with sqlcmd? i want to schedule that.